# anchor tag not working in safari (ios) for iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad

Tags: ios, html, ipad

This is what I have on my HTML5

```
<div class="google-play">
    <a href="http://example.com" role="button">
        <img src="img/google-play-btn.png"/>                                                                    
    </a>
</div>
```

and works fine on chrome, FF, android but doesn't seem to work on iPad.

Comment: And by not working you mean what exactly ?

Comment: you click and nothing happens

Comment: I just opened your html page at Safari, clicked and the link has been processed as expected. Same with http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_anchor. You'll have to explain what is the problem exactly.

Comment: Thank you, someone solved it. They gave me this Cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `touchend` event via jQuery on all anchor tags. For example:

```
$(function () {    
    $('a').on('click touchend', function() { 
        var link = $(this).attr('href');   
        window.open(link,'_blank'); // opens in new window as requested 

        return false; // prevent anchor click    
    });    
});
```

If you want to make the above iPhone and iPad specific function only, check to see if the "device" is an iPad, iPhone, etc. Like so:

```
$(function () {

    IS_IPAD = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
    IS_IPHONE = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) != null);

    if (IS_IPAD || IS_IPHONE) {

        $('a').on('click touchend', function() { 
            var link = $(this).attr('href');   
            window.open(link,'_blank'); // opens in new window as requested

            return false; // prevent anchor click    
        });     
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes ma'am! Cross-platform solution my friend. :)

Comment: But how do I make it open in a new page? This opens on the same page. Just what if I want to open in a new page?

Comment: Why not `click tap`? Touchend may run the risk of having someone lift their finger from a drag and triggering it, right?

Comment: Because `tap` requires jQuery Mobile, no?